# I've added the path to my chromedriver binary properly, but it is showing that binary not found, how do I fix this?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I've added the driver path to system property

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/k0r0/CFT/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver");
```

Getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

How do I resolve this?

Tried checking if my path was wrong but it isn't.

Comment: I've added the chrome binary to the /usr/bin path which has resolved this issue. but now I'm getting another error.
`Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) ` I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the extension at end of the line

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/k0r0/CFT/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver.exe");
```

Or:

If the first mechanism did not work then follow the below code, before that you have to upgrade your selenium version to 4+.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I'm on linux so adding .exe extension won't work. as for the second solution. I could use the selenium manager to figure this out. but I just wanted to know how to add a browserdriver and make it work. please check my comment on the same. apparently adding the chrome binary to bin worked in launching the chrome. but I'm facing the new issue.